# Device Controllers in OS

Tags: operating-systems

According to [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/device-driver-vs-device-controller-in-operating-system) article, we have the following:

> The device controller gets data from a connected system device and
> temporarily saves such data in a special purpose register inside the
> controller known as a local buffer.

So according to the above statement, the local buffer is a part of the special purpose registers of the controller. However, according to operating systems concepts, ninth edition, page 12, we have :

> A device controller maintains some local buffer storage and a set of
> special-purpose registers. The device controller is responsible for
> moving the data between the peripheral devices that it controls and
> its local buffer storage.

This means that a local buffer is a separate component from the set of special purpose registers of the controller, and hence, the local buffer is not a register. This makes more sense to me, since if we implement the local buffer as a register, the buffer will be limited in size as a register is limited in size. So my question is whether the local buffer of a device controller is implemented as a register or a separate memory module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the device and, specifically, how much data needs to be buffered.

Some devices, such as GPIO or SMBus (used for things like temperature sensors on the motherboard), have such a low bandwidth that the maximum amount of data that needs to be "buffered" is a small number of bytes. A hardware register or two is probably enough here.

Others, such as disk or ethernet, do not. In this case, using a more complex local buffer that isn't visible as a register may make more sense. Such a device would typically use DMA to transfer the contents of the buffer into core. However, computers sometimes boot from disk or over a network, so providing a slow register-based mechanism for reading the contents of the buffer can help simplify bootstrap loaders, both firmware and software.

As an example, on PC hardware, SATA disks are typically controlled through the Advanced Host Controller Interface, or [AHCI](https://wiki.osdev.org/AHCI) for short, which interfaces drives with the rest of the computer through DMA. However, they are still required to support what is known as [ATA PIO Mode](https://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_PIO_Mode), which reads the contents of the memory buffer through register-based port I/O. This is not recommended for operating systems in their steady state, but is very convenient for booting.